# How to connect to MS-SQL database via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I understand this is not best practice but I am operating within a limited realm and, as far as I can tell, this is the only solution to this problem.

I am trying to connect to an MS-SQL database both to get data and to put data onto the database. I cannot seem to do it through JavaScript.

ActiveXObject is, from my understanding, now depreciated so that is not working, which eliminates every functional solution that I could find recommended in the past.

Please note: I am not a web developer and I have no access to any of the standard web development tools for this task.

Comment: Get a back-end procedure! If you are not a web developer then you should be asking be right way to connect MY-SQL and apply best practice programming. ActiveXObject is bad practice, depreciated or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is the question has been asked multiple times in various forums - *Can my client-side Javascript (running in a browser) connect to a database server and fetch data?*

The short answer is - not recommended in general, not feasible without breaching security and without using outdated technologies. Let us dig into it.

**It is possible to connect to remote database from a browser using outdated technologies**

There are two pieces of technologies from `Java` and `.Net` worlds - `Applet` and `ActiveX` that run on the browser and can communicate to a remote database. The Java `Applet` is hardly used by anyone nowadays and browsers are stopping to support it. `ActiveX` is discontinued by Microsoft in their newer browser `Edge`. So, you have to enforce your target users to use old insecure browsers if you want to go with these options.

Do not use this.

**Use databases embedded in the browser and sync with a remote database**

You may use the database locally available in the browser and perform all read/write operations. Periodically sync this database with a remote one. Here are the options:

- `MongoDB` and use change stream to sync with a remote `MongoDB`
- `PouchDB` and sync with a remote `CouchDB` or even a `MySQL` database

Use this only for offline storage temporarily in the browser.

**The traditional and secure approach to connect to a remote Database**

Use a server-side technology to develop an app that your client-side code (`Javascript`, `HTML`) talks to. The app may provide `RESTful APIs` to interact from the client-side. Then the app that is running in a web server connects and interacts with the database. There are plenty of server-side technologies such as `Java`, `PHP`, `Python`, `NodeJS` (Javascript based), `.Net`, etc. to develop your server-side app.

Go with this option.

Answer (score 0):

Well javascript is a client side scripting where as your database runs on a server. So firstly you cannot connect to a database for executing any query from client side i.e javascript and also you need to setup a server side service which can connect to the database and execute the query and give you the result at the client side. You can refer any client-server architecture for this on the web.